# Dropwizard metrics annotations are not working in Spring Boot 1.5

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dropwizard, prometheus

I've integrated Spring Boot (1.5) based application with Dropwizard Metrics & Prometheus. I can see the DropWizard metrics in Prometheus when I use 'metricRegistry.mark()' method in my Controller class.

Now I want to show metrics related to Exceptions, so I added:

```
@ExceptionMetered(name="getMessages", cause=Exception.class)
@Counted(name = "getMessages")
public ResponseEntity<List<Message>> getMessages() {
```

But nothing related to exceptions shows up when I hit:
http://localhost:9001/metrics
http://localhost:9001/prometheus

I tried enabling ConsoleReporter as well:

```
@PostConstruct
public void startConsoleReporter() {
    consoleReporter = ConsoleReporter.forRegistry(dropwizardMetricRegistry)
            .convertRatesTo(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .convertDurationsTo(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build();
    consoleReporter.start(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

But it just keeps showing:

```
-- Meters ----------------------------------------------------------------------
myMeter
             count = 0
         mean rate = 0.00 events/second
     1-minute rate = 0.00 events/second
     5-minute rate = 0.00 events/second
    15-minute rate = 0.00 events/second
```

How can I get DropWizard annotations to work with Sprint Boot 1.5?

Comment: Hey, I feel that when using spring boot (and in general, given the state of the library) you should pick micrometer over dropwizard metrics (although, to be honest, I haven’t tried out micrometer yet)

Comment: Trust me, I would like to use Micrometer too! But we're on Spring Boot 1.5 and I don't believe Micrometer was integrated well with that version. Besides, there are other reasons our management wants to stick with DropWizard metrics -:(

Comment: As for micrometer with spring boot 1.5: https://github.com/TechPrimers/spring-boot-1.5-micrometer-prometheus-example

Comment: As for the preference of the management, I don’t know what it is but perhaps you have the responsibility to stress out the technical cost of using a library that is very inactive: last stable release was 8 months ago and issues can take months if not years to resolve via the main project.

Comment: This doesn't show how Micrometer can help with metrics related to Java Exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make Dropwizard annotations work in Spring Boot, you need an add-on like at [Metrics for Spring](http://metrics.ryantenney.com/). I've used it successfully in a project to wire up Dropwizard, Spring and Prometheus.

You'll find a minimal setup as the Version v0.1 in this repository: https://github.com/ahus1/prometheusspringbootminimal/tree/v0.1

Please note that later versions in this repository have been migrated to Micrometer with Spring Boot 1.5, and later to Micrometer with Spring Boot 2.0. I recommend using Micrometer instead of Dropwizard to get the additional information about metric descriptions into Prometheus. If you want support to convince your management, please get in contact using direct mail.

Comment: 'Metrics for Spring' link is not working -:( When you say.. "get in contact using direct mail", which email id should I use?